# Word problem based on ratio?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Problem statement,

In what ratio should a shopkeeper mix two types of rice, one costing `$20/kg`  and another costing `$10/kg` to get a rice variety costing  `$14/kg`.

Answer of this problem is 2:3

I am not able to develop intuition for this problem. Could somebody please help me out?

Comment: Read your problem carefully. There must be a typo since 14 appears twice. To gain some intuition, try various ways you might mix to get 100 kg of rice at the desired cost.

Comment: In rice costs / unit kg $y$ we have $y = 14 = 14 x + 10 (1 - x) $ with $x$ the fraction of the rice type which costs 14 \$/$kg$ in $1$ $kg$ of mixed rice. This is true if $x = 1$, i.e. there is only rice of type 14 \$/$kg$.

Comment: Hint solve $14 = 20x + 10(1 - x)$ for $x$, getting $x = 0.4$. So in $1$ $kg$ mixed rice there is $0.4$ $kg$ of type $20$ \$/$kg$ and $0.6$ $kg$ of type $10$ \$/$kg$ :).

Comment: @prcssngnr What does this equation represent? I am not able to visualize it. Can you explain the equation in answer section?

Comment: @prcssngnr lol timing :)

Comment: P.S. Please do not use tags without knowing their meaning. :) This is not a linear algebra question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach, let $x$ be the fraction of rice of type $20$ \$/$kg$ in the mixed rice then the total cost / $kg$ of mixed rice $y$ is $y = 20x + 10(1 - x)$.

Then, setting $y = 14$ and solving for $x$ we conclude $1$ $kg$ of mixed rice contains $0.4$ $kg$ of rice which costs $20$ \$/$kg$ and $0.6$ $kg$ of rice which costs $10$ \$/$kg$. This means for every $kg$ of mixed rice the ratio of the two rice types is $0.4 / 0.6 = 2 / 3$.

Answer (score 1):

The solution has already been posted before but I want to talk about **how** to develop the intuition of this equality since that is what you have asked for in the question.

Let's call the $2$ rice types Rice $1$ and Rice $2$ respectively. The key thing to notice is that we know the prices of all the types of rice (Rice $1$, Rice $2$ and the mixed rice). This encourages us to write an equality based on the prices of the original $2$ types of rice (i.e. **initial**) and the price of the mixed rice (i.e. **final**). In Algebra word problems like this, we always want to link the initial with the final (and this is where the intuition of our equality comes from). The solution proceed as follows:

Suppose you have $1$ kg of mixed rice and among those you have $x$ kg of Rice $1$ and $1-x$ kg of Rice $2$. Then, we plug in the prices of Rice $1$ and Rice $2$ to get

$$
20x+10(1-x)=14\\
20x+10-10x=14\\
10x=4\\
x=\frac{4}{10}\implies1-x=\frac{6}{10}
$$

So the ratio of the $2$ types of Rice will be

$$
\frac{4}{10}:\frac{6}{10}=4:6=\boxed{2:3}
$$